# JSON not retrieving data in FLUTTER

Tags: php, json, flutter

This is my code in **flutter**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('JSON ListView in Flutter')
        ),
        body: JsonListView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Fruitdata {
  String id;
  String fName;

  Fruitdata({
    this.id,
    this.fName,
  });

  factory Fruitdata.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Fruitdata(
      id: json['id'],
      fName: json['name'],
    //  fName: json['fruit_name'],
    );
  }
}

class JsonListView extends StatefulWidget {

  JsonListViewWidget createState() => JsonListViewWidget();

}

class JsonListViewWidget extends State<JsonListView> {

  final String uri = 'http://sha-way.freeweb.pk/index4.php';
//final String uri = 'https://flutter-examples.000webhostapp.com/fruites_list_file.php';

  Future<List<Fruitdata>> fetchFruits() async {

    var response = await http.get(uri);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      final items = json.decode(response.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      List<Fruitdata> listOfFruits = items.map<Fruitdata>((json) {
        return Fruitdata.fromJson(json);
      }).toList();

      return listOfFruits;
    }
    else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load data.');
    }

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Fruitdata>>(
      future: fetchFruits(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {

        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator()
        );

        return ListView(
          children: snapshot.data
              .map((data) => ListTile(
            title: Text(data.fName),
            onTap: (){print(data.fName);},
          ))
              .toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

the json i made is perfect i think ... 
You can notice in code i have comment the example ... 
 **//  fName: json['fruit_name'], and this //final String uri = 'https://flutter-examples.000webhostapp.com/fruites_list_file.php';**

now its retriving data fine from that part which i have comment but not from my JSON which is in code . The thing which i have notice is that may be because the example link contains **https://** and my code has **http://** is this what i am doing wrong or is there something else need help i am confused

Comment: I think it's the problem of your uri `http://sha-way.freeweb.pk/index4.ph` which probably is hosted freely. This type of site is not supported by non browser client call such as mobile. So, I think you should change your hosting. (I tested your code and got response in http format saying This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support )

Comment: yes right i also have figured out that i am using free hosting that's creating problem